# SweetAlert in Laravel 5.5 using laravel-mix not work properly with css

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-mix, sweetalert2

I try to use [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org) with Laravel 5.5 usin Larvel Mix, but not work properly

webpack.mix.js

```
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/assets/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist', 'public/js');
```

package.json

```
 "devDependencies": {
        ...
        "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
        ...
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^1.0",
        "sweetalert": "^2.0.8",
```

resource/assets/sass/app.css

```
// Sweet Alert
@import url("https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css");
```

when I execute `npm run dev` compiling without any errors.

But when I use with this method, alerts show without  CSS style of SweetAlert.

Answer (score 1):

After

```
npm install sweetalert2 --save
```

you should do like below in your app.js:

```
window.Swal = require('sweetalert2');
```

Or

```
@import "~sweetalert2";
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `resources/assets/sass/app.scss` file,

Use this line instead

```
@import "~sweetalert2";
```

What you were doing (importing the CSS from a CDN) has nothing to do with `npm` at all.

Comment: Thankyou , but is very older the question. Now I run Laravel 5.7, but thanks. @ru-chem-chong

Comment: I don't understand how Laravel 5.5 and Laravel 5.7 cause this to work differently.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `npm install sweetalert --save` run this command in your terminal/cmd.

Step 2: In your `resources/js/app.js` file,  simply import it into your application `import swal from 'sweetalert';`

[image]

Comment: It seems like this should work for me, but it does not.  It always says "Swal is not defined".  However, if I instead put "window.Swal = require('sweetalert2')" it will work.  What am I missing?

Comment: import swal from 'sweetalert';

window.swal = swal     Now,try this way